# Transform dataframe in specific way

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID Name Value
1  A    5%
2  B    7%
3  C    mean - 14.1, variance - 1.16
4  D    mean - 7.15, variance - 1.62
5  E    mean - 8.32, variance - 2.56
```

I want to transform that dataframe, so it looks like this:

```
ID Name Type        Value
1  A    value        5
2  B    value        7
3  C    mean        14.1
3  C    variance    1.16
4  D    mean        7.15
4  D    variance    1.62
5  E    mean        8.32
5  E    variance    2.56
```

So as you see, i added a column type with type of value of the row. When it has value with percent it has type value, and when it has value mean and variance, it must be separated into two rows with type mean and type variance. How could i do that?

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(ID = 1:5, Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
Value = c("5%", "7%", "mean - 14.1, variance - 1.16", 
"mean - 7.15, variance - 1.62", "mean - 8.32, variance - 2.56")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can bring the data into separate rows splitting on comma (`,`), `separate` the columns into two columns on `'-'` and get the data in numeric form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(Value, sep = ',') %>%
  separate(Value, c('Type', 'Value'), sep = '\\s+-\\s+', fill = "left") %>%
  mutate(Type = replace(Type, is.na(Type), 'value'), 
         Value = readr::parse_number(Value)))

#  ID Name      Type Value
#1  1    A     value  5.00
#2  2    B     value  7.00
#3  3    C      mean 14.10
#4  3    C  variance  1.16
#5  4    D      mean  7.15
#6  4    D  variance  1.62
#7  5    E      mean  8.32
#8  5    E  variance  2.56
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't remove percent sign from new dataframe as in desired dataframe

Comment: @french_fries Did you run `parse_number` step? It should remove `%` sign.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(Value, sep = ',') %>%
  separate(Value, c('Type', 'Value'), sep = '\\s+-\\s+', fill = "left") %>%
  mutate(Type = replace(Type, is.na(Type), 'value'), 
         Value = as.numeric(str_remove_all(Value, "\\D+"))))
```